# Cannot compile trigger for change log in oracle table

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I have a table named Customers. When I delete or update any value on the table, I'd like to log that to a new table which I create with below code. Problem is, I cannot get the old values (values that existed before deletion) to get inserted to the change log table. Code works only if I comment the old values part. What am I doing wrong?

The DDL statement for the log table creation :

```
CREATE TABLE customersHistory(
    tablename VARCHAR2(30),
    transactionType VARCHAR2(30),
    username VARCHAR2(30),
    transactionDate DATE,
    savedName VARCHAR2(50),
    savedSurname VARCHAR2(50));
```

and the code block to create concerned database trigger :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER custModify
AFTER DELETE OR UPDATE ON Customers
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  tableName    customersHistory.Tablename%type := 'Customers';
  typeOfChange customersHistory.Transactiontype%type;
  person       customersHistory.Username%type := USER;
  dateOfRecord customersHistory.Transactiondate%type;
  cname        customersHistory.Savedname%type;
  csurname     customersHistory.Savedsurname%type;        
BEGIN
    IF DELETING THEN
        typeOfChange :='Silme';
        dateOfRecord := SYSDATE;
        cname := OLD.c_name;
        csurname := OLD.c_surname;
    ELSIF UPDATING THEN
        typeOfChange :='Güncelleme';
        dateOfRecord := SYSDATE;
        cname := OLD.c_name;
        csurname:= OLD.c_surname;
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO customersHistory
    VALUES(tableName, typeOfChange, person, dateOfRecord, cname, csurname);

END;
```

error:

```
Trigger CUSTMODIFY compiled

LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
13/9      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
13/18     PLS-00201: identifier 'OLD.C_NAME' must be declared
14/9      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
14/21     PLS-00201: identifier 'OLD.C_SURNAME' must be declared
18/9      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
18/18     PLS-00201: identifier 'OLD.C_NAME' must be declared
19/9      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
19/20     PLS-00201: identifier 'OLD.C_SURNAME' must be declared
Errors: check compiler log
```

Comment: you need nothing but qualifying `OLD` identifiers by colons(`:`) such as `:OLD.C_NAME`

Comment: By the way, the assignments to `dateOfRecord`, `cname` and `csurname` are the same in both cases, so you could simplify the code by moving them outside the `if` condition - or even better, remove the variables and use the `:old` values and `sysdate` directly.